# How to do math manipulation with variables in conky?

Tags: conky, math

This is part of my conky code.

```
conky.config = {
    alignment = 'top_right',
    background = true,
    color2 = '2ECC71',
    cpu_avg_samples = 2,
    default_color = 'FFFFFF',
    double_buffer = true,
    font = 'Bitstream Vera Sans:size=8',
    gap_x = 25,
    gap_y = 13,
    minimum_width = 230,
    no_buffers = true,
    own_window = true,
    own_window_type = 'override',
    own_window_transparent = true,
    update_interval = 1.0,
    use_xft = true,
}

${voffset 20}${goto 40}${color e19e19}${cpugraph 14, $minimum_width e19e19 ffffff}
${goto 40}${color}CPU${font Bitstream Vera Sans:bold:size=8}$alignr$cpu%

${voffset 15}${goto 40}${color}${membar 14, $minimum_width}
${goto 40}${color}RAM${font Bitstream Vera Sans:bold:size=8}$alignr $mem / $memmax   $memperc%$font

${voffset 15}${goto 40}${color}${downspeedgraph eno1 14, 115 55ff55 55ff55} $alignr${upspeedgraph eno1 14, 115 554455 ff55ff}
```

Notice how with the CPU graph you can use the variable `$minimum_width`. I would like to yield half of this amount to each of the `downspeedgraph` and `upspeedgraph` (along with the necessary offset to do spacing in between).

The division operator `/` has no effect when I tried it. Is there a way to apply mathematical operations to variables in conky to achieve the intended effect?

Comment: I think you may be mistaken about `$minimum_width`. You cannot use variables like this. Try replacing it with 0 and you should see the same display. The easiest way to configure conky as you wish is to use something like `awk` to do replacements in the config and create the `.conkyrc` before running conky.

Comment: @meuh Could you please explain with an example? I'm entirely new to conky.

Answer (score 3):

Since conky is usually built to use `lua` there may be a cleaner solution involving that language, but here is a quick pre-processing script written in `perl`. It expects a simple configuration file, and extracts from the `conky.config={...}` part the variables being set. For example, `minimum_width = 230,` will create a perl variable of the same name and set it to that value.

Then it goes through the `conky.text=[[...]]` part and looks for expressions inside `@...@`. This assumes you do not use the `@` character for anything else. It then evaluates the perl expression you have put inside it. Perl also uses `$` in front of simple variables, so you can use expressions like `@$minimum_width/5@` and it will be replaced by 230/5 i.e. 46.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445140/119298
# parse conky 1.10 vars in conky.config and eval @expression@ in .text part
use strict;
use Safe;
my $pack = new Safe();
sub replace{
    my ($a,$body,$c) = @_;
#    $body =~ s/@(.*?)@/eval($1)/gse;
    $body =~ s/@(.+?)@/$pack->reval($1)/gse; # evaluate @expression@ using vars
    return $a.$body.$c;
}
my $config = join('',<>);
if($config =~ m/conky\.config\s*=\s*\{(.*?)\}/s){
    my $vars = "$1,";
    while($vars =~ m/\s*([a-z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*,/gs){
        ${$pack->varglob($1)} = $2;
    }
}
$config =~ s/(conky\.text\s*=\s*\[\[)(.*?)(\]\])/replace($1,$2,$3)/se;
print $config;
```

Put this script in a file, say `conkyparse`, and make it executable with `chmod +x conkyparse`. Move your `~/.conkyrc` file to say, `preconky` and edit it as given above, then before running conky, run `conkyparse <preconky >~/.conkyrc` to have the expressions calculated and replaced.

---

Note, you could also invent and use your own variable names. To avoid a conky error, you need to hide their definition inside a comment (a line starting `--`).
Here is an example `preconky` file:

```
conky.config = {
    minimum_width = 230,
 -- myvar = 22,
}
conky.text = [[
  ${goto @3*$myvar@} ${cpugraph 14,@$minimum_width/2@ e19e19 ffffff}
]]
```

and the resulting output file

```
conky.config = {
    minimum_width = 230,
 -- myvar = 22,
}
conky.text = [[
  ${goto 66} ${cpugraph 14,115 e19e19 ffffff}
]]
```